# MySQL Sum only specific category 0 otherwise

Tags: mysql, join, null, sum

There are some questions already like this, but I haven't found one exactly the same.

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, SUM(F.length) 
FROM actors A 
LEFT JOIN film_actors FA ON A.actor_id=FA.actor_id 
LEFT JOIN film F ON FA.film_id=F.film_id 
LEFT JOIN film_category FC ON FC.film_id=F.film_id 
LEFT JOIN category C ON FC.category_id=C.category_id 
WHERE C.name="Sci-Fi" 
GROUP BY A.last_name, A.first_name;
```

My issue is that I need to ONLY sum sci-fi for the sum, but I need report back all actors. If an actor has never been in a sci-fi movie they should be in the returned list but have 0 for their length. The `WHERE` is cutting out the ones with that don't have Sci-Fi movies which is the problem I'm just not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Change WHERE to AND, and (obviously) include a GROUP BY clause. Failing that, consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH a desired result.

Comment: I tried the WHERE to AND and that just made it return the SUM total for all the movies they have been in, likely because the left joins. That could be done with a much simpler query.

Comment: So, now you know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a CASE .... WHEN clause:

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN C.name="Sci-Fi" THEN F.length ELSE 0 END) 
FROM actors A 
LEFT JOIN film_actors FA ON A.actor_id=FA.actor_id 
LEFT JOIN film F ON FA.film_id=F.film_id 
LEFT JOIN film_category FC ON FC.film_id=F.film_id 
LEFT JOIN category C ON FC.category_id=C.category_id
GROUP BY A.last_name, A.first_name;
```

Comment: Ah haven't seen CASE WHEN before. That works really well. Still pretty new to MySQL.